# istringstream::str() does not return current contents

Tags: c++, stringstream

I have an `istringstream`, and I'm putting some data into it. Then, I extract some of the data I put in, and then I want to get the remaining contents of the `istringstream`. I thought, apparently incorrectly, that the following would do exactly that:

```
std::istringstream stream("Two words");
std::string word;
stream >> word;
std::cout << word << std::endl;
std::cout << stream.str() << std::endl;
```

The output is:

```
Two words
Two
Two words
```

In other words, the extraction operation is returning the correct value, and it's advancing the read pointer, as indicated by `tellg`, but `str` doesn't seem to care--it just returns the entire original contents of the `istringstream`.
I'm sure this is expected behavior, but I just can't fathom why.

So: **how can I easily and cleanly get the remaining contents of the `istringstream`, and why isn't `str` doing it already?**

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why isn't str doing it already?

Because that is [documented](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream/str) behavior of this method:

> Returns a copy of the underlying string as if by calling rdbuf()->str().

It always returns whole underlying string

> how can I easily and cleanly get the remaining contents of the istringstream

Just change your code to:

```
std::cout << stream.rdbuf() << std::endl;
```

[live example](http://ideone.com/YPmszP)

output is:

```
Two
 words
```

Answer (score 0):

> and why isn't str doing it already?

I am sure some people will want it one way while others will want it another way.

> how can I easily and cleanly get the remaining contents of the `istringstream`>

That's not too hard. Use:

```
std::cout << stream.str().substr(stream.tellg()) << std::endl;
```